# Claims-based authorization in ASP.NET MVC with external authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I made quite a research on this matter and now need a second opinion on a problem with scenario like this:

I'll have to implement an authorization based on claims which will get from external provider (another team provide this authentication via WCF service). They provided me a `Claims` which contains only name of role that authenticated user have assign(single user can be assign to multiple roles) for and based on that I need to authorize most of my `controllers` `methods`. On different level of action permitted for different roles for example lets get `Role` named `Moderator` which have permission to `Read` and `Write` but couldn't `Delete` records of some resource. My idea is to `cache` some `list` of `custom class` contains 3 `fields` : `string ResourceName`,`List<string> Action`,`string Role` generated from xml file at start of application. And then in `CheckAccess` `method` of `CustomClaimsAuthorizationManager` which inherits from `ClaimsAuthorizationManager`.

**First Question:**

Have anyone some experience with similar scenarios before? Is there any better solution than that described above by me?

**I don't want to `override` any `MembershipProvider`**

Comment: Sounds like you just need to write your own authorization filter attribute which performs the necessary checks. I might be missing something though

Comment: But what about storing all needed information in xml file is it good idea or maybe better is to put it in json?

Comment: Why not just add a table to your existing membership database?

Comment: we got multitenant application so it would be multiplicated information in x database.

Comment: Don't optimize prematurely. Your primary concern seems to be caching roles. However, first make it working and then think of adding a cache. It is really not important whether the information for the cache will come from XML, database or anything else.